# Let $Y$ be a set, and let $f: \mathbb{N} \to Y$ be a function. Then $f(\mathbb{N})$ is at most countable.

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Prove Proposition $8.1.8$: Let $Y$ be a set, and let $f: \mathbb{N} \to Y$ be a function.
>   Then $f(\mathbb{N})$ is at most countable.
>
> (Hint: the basic problem here is that
>   $f$ is not assumed to be one-to-one. Define $A$ to be the set $A :=$ {$n \in \mathbb{N} : f(m) \not= f(n)$ for all $0 \le m < n$}; informally speaking, $A$ is the set of natural numbers $n$ for which $f(n)$ does not appear in the sequence $f(0), f(1),...f(n − 1)$. Prove that when $f$ is restricted to $A$, it becomes a bijection from $A$ to $f(\mathbb{N})$. Then use Proposition $8.1.5$).

Let's restrict $f$ to $A$. Then $f$ is injective since if $f(m) \not= f(n)$, then $m < n$ by definition. Suppose there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)$ exists but $n \not \in A$. This will mean that $f(n) = f(m)$ for some $0 \le m < n$. But since $f(n) = f(m)$ and $f$ is injective $n=m$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

I know that all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are at most countable i.e. either finite or countable. $A$ is not finite since than there would be some $t \le n$ for all $t \in A$, but that should mean that starting from $n+1$ all $f(n+k) = f(m)$ for all $n+1 \le m < n+k$. To be honest, I don't see here any contradiction. However, following the hint, there should be one. Can you help me with this part? Also, can you check the thoughts concerning the bijectivity of the restricted $f$?

If I know that $A$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ then I have a proposition $8.1.5$ (page $183$, Terence Tao-Analysis $1$), which says that $A$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$, and therefore will be countable. From the existence of bijection from $A$ to $f(\mathbb{N})$ it will follow that $f(\mathbb{N})$ is countable.

Comment: If $f(m)\neq f(n)$ then $m<n$? Really?

Comment: Surely $f(N)$ has at most as many elements of $N$ so this is obvious

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I mean, if $m, n \in A$, then it is true, isn't it? The f was restricted to $A$.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Maybe it is obvious, but I would like to prove it. If you can help me I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Your paragraph about $A$ being non-finite doesn't make sense to me.  $A$ could be either finite or non-finite depending on what $f$ is.  Consider $Y=\mathbb N$ and $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=1$ as two possible examples.  The only important thing about $A$ is that it cannot possibly be uncountable.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I don't understand too why it should be non-finite. However, the hint that is given in the book suggests to show that the restricted $f$ is bijective and than use the following proposition: "Let $X$ be an infinite subset of the natural numbers $N$. Then there exists a unique bijection $f : N → X$ which is increasing, in the sense that $f(n + 1) > f(n)$ for all $n ∈ N$. In particular, $X$ has equal cardinality with $N$ and is hence countable". Therefore, I think that I should now show that $A$ is infinite to be able to use the proposition.

Comment: Okay, I'll go dig out my copy of Tao and see what he's trying to get at.  ^_^

Comment: @MatthewDaly In case it will be helpful, it is the Exercise $8.1.4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y'=f(\mathbb N)$. Let's come up with a one-to-one correspondence between $Y'$ and a subset of $\mathbb N$.

$$g(y)=\min\{n\in\mathbb N\mid f(n)=y\}\quad \text{for all }y\in Y'$$

This is well-defined since each of those sets is guaranteed to be non-empty.  $g(Y')$ is exactly the set $A$ that Tao is suggesting we consider, and $g$ is exactly the bijection between $A$ and $Y'$.  You are correct that $f$ restricted to this $A$ is a bijection, because it is the inverse of $g$.

So we now want to say that $A$ is at most countable.  $A$ is either finite or infinite.  If it is finite (for instance, $f(n)$ might be the remainder when you divide $n$ by $4$, in which case $A=\{0,1,2,3\}$), then it is at most countable by the definition of "at most countable".  On the other hand, if $A$ is infinite (for instance you might have $f(n)=\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$, in which case $A$ is the set of all  even numbers), then it is at most countable by Proposition 8.1.5.

Comment: It's fine, but since the OP is not happy simply by having trivially a surjection from $\Bbb N$ to $f(\Bbb N)$, you have to wonder first what kind of arguments they will be happy with.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to help you to finish my work, following the hint given in the question.

Comment: I edited the question to outline specifically what I don't understand.

Comment: @user13 Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!